# How to use customer email address as their own coupon code in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use customer email address as their own coupon code with a special discount. To achieve this I tried bellow code but nothing happen shows error `Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo()`. Is it possible to use coupon code virtually not saving like custom `post_type`?

Here is the code what I'm trying so far.

```
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();
$user_email = $current_user->user_email ;

$coupon_code = $user_email; // Code
$amount = '10'; // Amount
$discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

// Add meta
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
```

Comment: Change from `get_currentuserinfo()` to `wp_get_current_user()`. The first has been deprecated since 4.5 (assuming you are higher than this). https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo & https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [**`get_currentuserinfo()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/) function is deprecated. Use **`wp_get_current_user()`** instead.

You should use in your code:

```
// (Optional) depending where you are using this code
is_user_logged_in(){

    global $current_user;

    // If global $current_user is not working
    if(empty($current_user))
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Here goes all your other code below… …

}
```

After that, I have never tried to set an email as coupon code slug programatically, but it should work as it's possible to set in woocommerce a coupon code with an email address (I have test it with success)…

Comment: `is_user_logged_in()` seems to be a must here. According to the codex. https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user#Checking_Other_User_Attributes, the code example above is better than the default usage itself.

Comment: ok , `is_user_logged_in()` is not working if it not inside a function or class.  Is it possible to use coupon code virtually not saving like custom post_type?

Comment: @Firefog I don't think so, you need to make it real, as WC_cart object is checking through it's methods if that coupon exist to apply it and to process it on checkout… For the `is_user_logged_in()`, you can use it in a function with your code on function.php file. Then you can call the function where you want.

Comment: Thanks I already did it. And I found there is no way virtually use a coupon. But it only can possible in real That mean I must have to create a coupon post first. Thanks for the clearance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_action( 'user_register', 'coupon_email', 10, 1 );

    function coupon_email( $user_id ) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['email_address'] ) )
            $coupon = array(
        'post_title' => $_POST['email_address'],
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
    );

    $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

}
```

This will add a coupon with the users email address as the title and input every time a new user registers for your website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already figure this. But I need  Is it possible to use coupon code virtually not saving like custom post_type? So the coupon only work when they input on checkout no need to save on database or no need coupon tracking